# Console doesn't work online

Tags: symfony

I'm using **Symfony2.6** and I have a problem with **CoreSphereConsoleBundle**. it works good in local but not working online. When I run a command, **"Loading ..."** appears in the console and nothing happens no execution. How can I solve that ?

**dev.log**

```
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] request.INFO: Matched route "console" (parameters: "_controller": "CoreSphere\ConsoleBundle\Controller\ConsoleController::consoleAction", "_route": "console") [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DumpListener::configure". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Subscriber\SlidingPaginationSubscriber::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:11] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelFinishRequest". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
[2015-08-05 15:18:12] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
```

Comment: check the logs in app/log ?

Comment: I have added dev.log

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No , the console is displayed well in the browser